# Finding all zeroes of $f(z) =-\sin^2(z)+2\cos(z)-2=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the zeroes of the function:

$f(z)=-\sin^2(z)+2\cos(z)-2 $

So far I have the following:

$-\sin^2(z)+2\cos(z)-2=0 $

$\cos^2(z)-1+2\cos(z)-2=0$

$\cos^2(z)+2\cos(z)-3=0$

Solving the quadratic setting $w=\cos(z)$ I get:

$w^2+2w-3=0$

$w=1$ or $w=-3$

Leaving me with:

$\cos(z)=1$ or $\cos(z)=-3$

Continuing with the first equation I get:

$\cos(z)=\frac {e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=1$

$e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=2$

$e^{i(x+iy)}+e^{-i(x+iy)}=2$

$e^{ix}e^{-y}+e^{-ix}e^{y}=2$

$e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))+e^{y}(\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x))=2$

$e^{-y}(\cos(x)+i\sin(x))+e^{y}(\cos(x)-i\sin(x))=2$

$(e^{-y}+e^{y})(\cos(x)+i(e^{-y}-e^{y})\sin(x)=2+0i$

By equality of complex numbers we must have:

$(e^{-y}+e^{y})\cos(x)=2$ and $(e^{-y}-e^{y})\sin(x)=0$

From the first equation it seems that $y=0$ is forced for it to make sense which in turn forces $x=2\pi*k$, $k$ being an integer.

But does this account for all the zeroes of the function f? Wolfram Alpha suggests solutions I can't make sense of.

Thank you

Comment: You ignores the $\cos z=-3$ case, it seems?

Comment: In the case $cos(z)=-3$ I get:

$(e^{-y}+e^{y})cos(x)=-6$ and $(e^{-y}-e^{y})sin(x)=0$

The second equation would demand that $y=0$ or $x=\pi*k$, with $k$ an integer.

The first equation makes no sense to me.. what am I failing to see?

Comment: Why do you say the first equation doesn't make sense?

Comment: I can't see how I can find x and y's that solves it. Maybe I don't need to? I feel I lost track of the task after finding the real zeroes

Comment: Maybe you've realised it by now, but you *can* solve $e^{-y} + e^y = 6$ in $\mathbb{R}$ (in the same way that you would rigorously prove that $e^{-y} + e^y = 2$ has only one solution $y = 0$). Hint: what was the approach you took to look at the zeroes of $f$ in the first place?

Comment: I see now that $(e^{-y}+e^{y})cos(x)=-6$ can be solved by setting $y=log(3\pm2\sqrt2)$ and $x=\pi+2\pi*k$ , $k$ being an integer.

Did I find all the zeroes of the original function f now? If thats the case would the following be the answer?

$f(2\pi*k+i*0)=0$

$f(\pi+2\pi*k+i*log(3+2\sqrt2)=0$

$f(\pi+2\pi*k+i*log(3-2\sqrt2)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solutions**

The solutions are *with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$*:
$$
\begin{align*}
z &= 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi\\
z &= 2 \cdot \left( k \cdot \pi \pm \operatorname{arctanh}(\sqrt{2}) \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

**How to solve**

To find these solutions you can simply rearrange your equation as follows (the way of factorization):
$$
\begin{align*}
f(z) &= -\sin(z)^{2} + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 2\\
0 &= -\sin(z)^{2} + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 2 \quad\mid\quad \text{use } 1 = \sin(z)^{2} + \cos(z)^{2} \Rightarrow \sin(z)^{2}  = -\cos(z)^{2} + 1\\
0 &= -\left( -\cos(z)^{2} + 1 \right) + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 2\\
0 &= \cos(z)^{2} - 1 + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 2\\
0 &= \cos(z)^{2} + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 3 \quad\mid\quad \text{use factorization
}\\
0 &= \left( \cos(z) - 1 \right) \cdot \left( \cos(z) + 3 \right) \quad\mid\quad \text{use the zero product theorem}\\
\\
(1.) \qquad 0 &= \cos(z) - 1\\
&\text{and}\\
(2.) \qquad 0 &= \cos(z) + 3\\
\\
(1.) \qquad 0 &= \cos(z) - 1 \quad\mid\quad +1\\
(1.) \qquad 1 &= \cos(z)  \quad\mid\quad \arccos()\\
(1.) \qquad \arccos(1) &= \arccos(\cos(z))\\
(1.) \qquad \arccos(1) &= z\\
(1.) \qquad z &= \arccos(1)\\
(1.) \qquad z &= 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi\\
\\
(2.) \qquad 0 &= \cos(z) + 3 \quad\mid\quad -3\\
(2.) \qquad -3 &= \cos(z) \quad\mid\quad \arccos()\\
(2.) \qquad \arccos(-3) &= \arccos(\cos(z))\\
(2.) \qquad \arccos(-3) &= z\\
(2.) \qquad z &= \arccos(-3) \quad\mid\quad \text{use } \arccos(z) = -\mathrm{i} \cdot \ln\left( \mathrm{i} \cdot \sqrt{1 - z^{2}} + z \right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= -\mathrm{i} \cdot \ln\left( \mathrm{i} \cdot \sqrt{1 - 3^{2}} + (-3) \right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= -\mathrm{i} \cdot \ln\left( \mathrm{i} \cdot \sqrt{1 - 3^{2}} - 3 \right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= -\mathrm{i} \cdot \ln\left( \mathrm{i} \cdot \sqrt{1 - 9} + 3 \right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= -\mathrm{i} \cdot \ln\left( \mathrm{i} \cdot \sqrt{-8} - 3 \right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= -\mathrm{i} \cdot \ln\left( \mathrm{i} \cdot \sqrt{8} \cdot \mathrm{i} + 3 \right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= -\mathrm{i} \cdot \ln\left( -\sqrt{8} - 3 \right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= -\mathrm{i} \cdot \left(2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot \mathrm{i} \pm \left( -1.76274717\dots + \pi \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)\right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot \pm \left( \pi + 1.76274717\dots \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= 2 \cdot \left(k \cdot \pi \pm \left(\frac{\pi}{2} + 0.8814\dots \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)\right)\\
(2.) \qquad z &= 2 \cdot \left( k \cdot \pi \pm \operatorname{arctanh}(\sqrt{2}) \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)\\
\\
(1.) \qquad z &= 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi\\
(2.) \qquad z &= 2 \cdot \left( k \cdot \pi \pm \operatorname{arctanh}(\sqrt{2}) \cdot \mathrm{i} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

You can also solve it by substitution:

$$
\begin{align*}
f(z) &= -\sin(z)^{2} + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 2\\
0 &= -\sin(z)^{2} + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 2 \quad\mid\quad \text{use } 1 = \sin(z)^{2} + \cos(z)^{2} \Rightarrow \sin(z)^{2}  = -\cos(z)^{2} + 1\\
0 &= -\left( -\cos(z)^{2} + 1 \right) + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 2\\
0 &= \cos(z)^{2} - 1 + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 2\\
0 &= \cos(z)^{2} + 2 \cdot \cos(z) - 3 \quad\mid\quad u := \cos(z)\\
0 &= u^{2} + 2 \cdot u - 3 \quad\mid\quad + 3\\
3 &= u^{2} + 2 \cdot u \quad\mid\quad \text{complete square by } +\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^{2}\\
3 + \left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^{2} &= u^{2} + 2 \cdot u + \left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^{2} \quad\mid\quad a^{2} + 2 \cdot a \cdot b + b^{2} = \left(a + b \right)^{2}\\
3 + \left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^{2} &= \left(u + \frac{2}{2}\right)^{2}\\
3 + \left(1\right)^{2} &= \left(u + 1\right)^{2}\\
3 + \left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^{2} &= \left(u + \frac{2}{2}\right)^{2}\\
3 + 1 &= \left(u + 1\right)^{2}\\
3 + \left(\frac{2}{2}\right)^{2} &= \left(u + \frac{2}{2}\right)^{2}\\
4 &= \left(u + 1\right)^{2} \quad\mid\quad \sqrt{~~}\\
\pm\sqrt{4} &= u + 1\\
u + 1 &= \pm\sqrt{4}\\
u + 1 &= \pm2 \quad\mid\quad -1\\
u &= \pm2 - 1 \quad\mid\quad u := \cos(z)\\
\cos(z) &= \pm2 - 1\\
\\
(1.) \qquad 0 &= \cos(z) - 1\\
&\text{and}\\
(2.) \qquad 0 &= \cos(z) + 3\\
\\
&\text{yet it's the same as above}
\end{align*}
$$

Are there still queations?